# VS Code: Pluggin auto close class scss

Tags: css, saas, visual-studio-code, plug-in

I'm looking for a plugin how can auto close brackets and put and comment like that :

```
.my-class{
    css code
} // /.my-class
```

or

```
label{
    code
}// /label
```

Is it possible to find something like that ?